# putting output of script to variable in loop bash

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I have the following bash script and want to run other script from that and capture the results:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
     echo "exit" | out=`python file.py`
     if [[ $out == *"WORD"* ]]; then
        echo $line >> out.txt
     fi
done<$1
```

But this is not working for me. In each iteration `out` wouln't get value...

Comment: `echo "exit" | out=\`python file.py\`` should be something like `echo "exit" && out=\`python file.py\`` or `out=\`echo "exit" | python file.py\`` depends on what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "exit" | out=`python file.py`
```

Should be something like (send "exit" to the result of assigning the output of `file.py` to out - seems odd):

```
echo "exit" && out=`python file.py`
```

or (send "exit" as input to file.py and assign output to `out`):

```
out=`echo "exit" | python file.py`
```

depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Keep `python execution` outside loop since that is not dependent upon any loop variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

# initialize output file
> out.txt

# execute python script
out=$(echo "exit" | python file.py)

# loop
while read -r line; do
   [[ "$out" == *"WORD"* ]] && echo "$line" >> out.txt
done < "$1"
```

Also quoting seem to be missing at many point that I have added.

Comment: What happened fo `echo exit`, which the python script apparently needs to read.

Answer (score 1):

A pipeline runs in a subshell, so variable assignments within it aren't visible in the parent shell. It should be:

```
out=$(echo exit | python file.py)
```

Now the whole pipeline is inside the command substitution, but the variable assignment is in the original shell.